# How to unit test async code which has DispatchQueue.main.async in it

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I've written below swift code

```
public func authenticateTouchID(completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
  .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
  localizedReason: NSLocalizedString("temp", comment: ""),
  reply: { (result, error) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      guard let error =  error else {
        completion(result, nil)
        return
      }
      completion(result, error)
    }
}
)}
```

and while unit test it I'm facing issue.
This works perfectly on local but while generating teamcity build it get failed.

please let me know how can I unit test above piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first suggest eliminating the extra code around calling your completion handler. The guard statement is redundant.

```
public func authenticateTouchID(completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
  .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
  localizedReason: NSLocalizedString("temp", comment: ""),
  reply: { (result, error) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      completion(result, error)
    }
  }
)}
```

Next, I would suggest passing in the queue that you want to run the completion on ... but with a default value of `DispatchQueue.main` so that your application call sites don't change but in your test code you can pass in something else.

```
public func authenticateTouchID(completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void, onQueue queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main) {
authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
  .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
  localizedReason: NSLocalizedString("temp", comment: ""),
  reply: { (result, error) -> Void in
    queue.async {
      completion(result, error)
    }
  }
)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Price Ringo for your help. It worked for me.

Comment: I made one change to make it run without warning. Moved queue parameter at first position and then completion handler.